# Sparklyr connection error: Error in spark_connect_gateway(gatewayAddress, gatewayPort, sessionId, : Gateway in localhost:8880 did not respond

Tags: r, sparklyr

I am having the following issue while connecting to sparkyr.

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
* Using Spark: 2.4.3
Error in spark_connect_gateway(gatewayAddress, gatewayPort, sessionId,  : 
  Gateway in localhost:8880 did not respond.


Try running `options(sparklyr.log.console = TRUE)` followed by `sc <- spark_connect(...)` for more debugging info.
```

Some info:

```
spark_installed_versions()
  spark hadoop
1 2.4.3    2.7
                                                               dir
1 C:\\Users\\88015\\AppData\\Local/spark/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7
```

I tried out many suggestions from google but I could not fix this issue. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug that's being fixed. see response from yitao-li in
https://github.com/sparklyr/sparklyr/issues/3129

Comment: Thanks. Anyways I have managed to fix this error using some information on java home directory. The key was to have older java version...8 or less.